# AWS does not show me the "S3 Bucket" option when importing Data From Amazon S3 to a New MySQL DB Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

Following the documentation on [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.html) I am trying to restore a database from an s3 file.

However on my console the "Specify source backup details" option does not appear, is this documentation outdated? Am I doing something terribly wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need to access from the [RDS consoles Database screen](https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/home#databases:) (before the wizard). To the left of the `Create database` button is a button labelled `Restore from S3` as shown in the image below.

[image]

Clicking this button will take you to the [Wizard](https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/home?#restore-from-s3:) you're expecting.